# Using function as while parameter like Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I'm developing a CMS and developers can create custom theme. They are using foreach for get posts but I want them to use while. Because with foreach they can define different variable names. (example: foreach($array => $variable) ) so I cant define functions for $variable.

```
$array = array(
array(
    'title' => 'title 1', 
    'content' => 'content 1', 
),
array(
    'title' => 'title 2', 
    'content' => 'content 2', 
),
array(
    'title' => 'title 3', 
    'content' => 'content 3', 
),
);
function get_array() {
    i++;
    global $array[i];
    return $array[i];
}
function get_title() {
    echo $array[i]['title'];
}
function get_content() {
    echo $array[i]['title'];
}
while (get_array()) {
    echo get_title();
    echo get_content();
}
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    # developer can define new variable name. so they cant use get_title() function for different variable name
}
```

Why I dont want to use foreach?
for example (nice code):

```
$array = array(
array(
    'title' => 'title 1', 
    'content' => 'content 1', 
),
array(
    'title' => 'title 2', 
    'content' => 'content 2', 
),
array(
    'title' => 'title 3', 
    'content' => 'content 3', 
),
);
function get_array() {
    global $array;
    return $array;
}
function get_title() {
    global $page;
    echo $page['title'];
}
function get_content() {
    global $page;
    echo $page['content'];
}
foreach (get_array() as $key => $page) {
    get_title();
    get_content();
}
die();
```

but they using Page instead of a different name, functions doesnt works. like this:

```
foreach (get_array() as $key => $item) {
    get_title();
    get_content();
}
```

Comment: IMHO, a foreach would be better than WP's `get_title()` etc. Just have an array with objects and let the developers iterate through it how ever they want and just have methods on them, like. `$obj->title();` and so on. It's horrible when the same function can return different results because of some state have changed somewhere else, that you might not even be aware about. Being too strict most often just leads to frustration for the devs.

Comment: You should also look into OOP instead of creating a bunch of global functions that are dependent on some internal state.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not understand "some state have changed somewhere else". What kind of change are you talking about? how to return different results? And by the way I mean if developer using foreach with different variable name, functions doenst works. Because get_title give $page['title'] but developer can use different name. example $p.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My CMS fully object-oriented. But I'm creating functions for make easy

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you are trying to say in your question. Certainly a programmer can define variables in his code. It does not make a difference if a `foreach` or a `while` loop is used. The issue I see with your approach is that you have no separation whatsoever between the different layers. That basically means they can break or modify _anything_ by purpose or by accident.

Comment: I honestly don't see how `while(get_array()): echo get_title();` would be so much easier than `foreach (get_array() as $page): echo $page->title();` or `while($page = get_array()): echo $page->title()`. If anything, I would say that the first example (with functions) are less declarative. If you have the page object in a variable (like `$page`), you can easily pass it along to other methods and functions.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry for my English. English is not my main language. I edited question with example. I hope it will clear for you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you so much for your interest. CMS core created fully of OOP. But developer side should be simple like wordpress. Only few functions and while loops. Like you told `while(get_array()): echo get_title();` is best way for me. I failed to do that. How i can do this?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh sorry now i understand you. Are you saying, use object in foreach? It will be best! I will try.

Comment: I'm saying that your `get_array()` should only return an array (or object that can be iterated on) with page objects. Each page object can then have a method called `title()` that returns the title. Then the page object is isolated and can be passed around. This will give the developers _way_ more freedom. Don't create a structure that will only work if you use it _exactly_ like you want. That's when developers jump on to the next CMS. Restricting how you can use your CMS just "to make it easier" will most likely come back and bite you. There's always edge cases that won't fit your design.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for answer. Like I told I created all of CMS with OOP. But I want to create simple functions for developers. But way of Magnus is the better then my way. `foreach (get_array() as $page): echo $page->title();` is best. but how can i create new object in all iterations?

Comment: _"how can i create new object in all iterations"_ - You just return an array that contains the objects.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks a lot Magnus! I will create new function which returns an array of objects. And It will be best! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help (and, in my opinion, prevent you from making a bad design decision :-)

Comment: You did not understand at all what I wrote, apparently.